# How to remove a property from a custom user control

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

A property was added to a custom user control. Since then, Visual Studio has inserted generated code to every form that uses that user control. Now we want to remove that property because it is not going to be used. But obviously doing so causes compile errors. Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to remove the property from all that generated code? It seems to me that putting something like [Obsolete()]  should be enough to tell Visual Studio to remove it from the generated code. Is there some other way?

Comment: ASP.NET Web Forms? MVC? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: This should be valid for Win and Web forms.

Comment: @leppie, Not necessarily. AFAIR, web form user controls don't insert generated code regarding properties, only a reference to the Type of the control (or file location). In that case, search and replace may be the best answer. In WinForms, it's a whole different ball of wax that I'm not familiar with. Hence the question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: That's true now that I think of it (everything goes to the HTML side). Components does have designer services though. Save to say this must be WInforms :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex to the rescue! What I usually do is open Replace in Files dialog (Ctrl+Shift+H), check Use Regular Expressions checkbox and replace instances of `.+\.SomeProperty.+` with empty string.

Be sure to commit your changes to repository *before* this, so you can revert to working state if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick - remove the generated code from all the affected files quickly and easily.

Answer (score 4):

Look at [`DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute`](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute), especially the `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden` option.

**Caveat:** Unfortunately you will have to open every form/control in design mode so the code can be regenerated (if it does not do so already).

Comment: This is a great idea! while it doesn't remove the generated code, I will use it from now on to prevent the generated code. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use some refactoring tool, like Resharper.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Adding the "Obsolete" atribute will only generate a compiler warning, but wont remove any code.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave it and mark it as [`Obsolete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22kk2b44%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).